# How to get accurate width without horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

In Qt, I have created a QGraphicsScene as shown below.

```
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,152,720);
m_view = new QGraphicsView(m_scene);
```

Now the window is created with horizontal and vertical scrollbars. Since I don’t want to use horizontal scroll bar, it used the code

`m_view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy (Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);`

But at this time,  there is no horizontal scrollbar and the width is not 150, it is 140 something. How to get accurate width without horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the inner width of your QGraphicsView, you can simply subtract the width of the scrollbar from the total width. This is how I would do it:

```
int innerWidth = width();
if (verticalScrollBar()) innerWidth -= verticalScrollBar()->width();
```

Comment: i don't want to get the inner width, i want to show the window in 152 width without scroll bar

Comment: @indira, in that case set the width of m_scene to `152 + m_view->verticalScrollBar()->width()`

Comment: I found a small issue using this if the vertical scrollbar exists, but hasn't been used yet, and Qt returns 100 as the default scrollbar width. The simple fix is: `if (verticalScrollBar() && verticalScrollBar()->isVisible()) ...`

Comment: @steveo225 The comment I was looking for! I have faced similar issue: in window's constructor, child widgets inherited from `QAbstractScrollArea` return 100x30 as size for both horizontal and vertical scroll bars, but after the window is shown, sizes are changed.

Fix: override the `showEvent` (works for `QDialog`).